# Hash table with two keys

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

I have a large amount of data the I want to be able to access in two different ways.  I would like constant time look up based on either key, constant time insertion with one key, and constant time deletion with the other.  Is there such a data structure and can I construct one using the data structures in tr1 and maybe boost?

Comment: Will you be adding new data to this structure?

Comment: It should be self-evident that insertion requires knowledge of ALL keys.

Comment: Don't see how you can meet your requirements... worst case performance for a hash table is O(n), not O(1).

Comment: @Billy Oneal I care about average performance, for which I think hash tables give me O(1).

Comment: If you are adding and removing data, you cannot get O(1).  With hash tables, even if you used a [universal hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing) you will still get collisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two parallel hash-tables.  Make sure that the keys are stored inside the element value, because you'll need all the keys during deletion.

Comment: Could you kindly give some examples/clarifications for beginners?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Bloom Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)?  They aren't O(1), but I think they perform better than hash tables in terms of both time and space required to do lookups.

Comment: Bloom Filters are probabilistic. They don't give exact answers. (And they don't work with two keys natively as the OP wants)

Comment: They do not give exact answers, but they do decrease the number of hashes one has to do in order to determine if an element is a member of a set.

Comment: Err.. but they don't determine if the element is in the set.

Comment: You are correct.  If an element is said, by a bloom filter, to be in the set, you'll need to determine if the element is in the backing store again.  But, the number of times needed to check the backing store will be much smaller than the number of times needed if you used only a hash table.

Comment: Comparing Bloom filters with hash tables is a bit of an apples & oranges kind of thing... A Bloom filter is just going to tell you if a key belongs to a set of keys, you still need to store the key -> value mapping somewhere (else). And also Bloom filters are a bit tricky when you want to delete keys.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to find why you need to do this but as someone said try using 2 different hashtables.
Just pseudocode in here:

```
Hashtable inHash;
Hashtable outHash;

//Hello myObj example!!
myObj.inKey="one";
myObj.outKey=1;
myObj.data="blahblah...";

//adding stuff
inHash.store(myObj.inKey,myObj.outKey);
outHash.store(myObj.outKey,myObj);

//deleting stuff
inHash.del(myObj.inKey,myObj.outKey);
outHash.del(myObj.outKey,myObj);

//findin stuff

//straight
myObj=outHash.get(1);

//the other way; still constant time

key=inHash.get("one");
myObj=outHash.get(key);
```

Not sure, thats what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the limits of the design of standard containers: a container in a sense "own" the contained data and expects to be the only owner... containers are not merely "indexes".
For your case a simple, but not 100% effective, solution is to have two std::maps with "Node *" as value and storing both keys in the Node structure (so you have each key stored twice). With this approach you can update your data structure with reasonable overhead (you will do some extra map search but that should be fast enough).

A possibly "correct" solution however would IMO be something like

```
struct Node
{
    Key key1;
    Key key2;
    Payload data;
    Node *Collision1Prev, *Collision1Next;
    Node *Collision2Prev, *Collision2Next;
};
```

basically having each node in two different hash tables at the same time.

Standard containers cannot be combined this way. Other examples I coded by hand in the past are for example an hash table where all nodes are also in a doubly-linked list, or a tree where all nodes are also in an array.

For very complex data structures (e.g. network of structures where each one is both the "owner" of several chains and part of several other chains simultaneously) I even resorted sometimes to code generation (i.e. scripts that generate correct pointer-handling code given a description of the data structure).